# Drawing specified part of QPainterPath on QImage [zoom and pan]

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

i.e. if I specify some cubic lines from example specified in  [Qt5 tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html):

```
QPainterPath path;
path.addRect(20, 20, 60, 60);

path.moveTo(0, 0);
path.cubicTo(99, 0,  50, 50,  99, 99);
path.cubicTo(0, 99,  50, 50,  0, 0);

QPainter painter(this);
painter.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100, Qt::white);
painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(79, 106, 25), 1, Qt::SolidLine,
                    Qt::FlatCap, Qt::MiterJoin));
painter.setBrush(QColor(122, 163, 39));

painter.drawPath(path);
```

which constructs this set of curves[image]

Now I'd like to render only a part of those curves on `QImage` specified by some region  with starting point=[20px,50px] with width=80px and height=50px so resulting would look like this:[image]

Or if it is possible, to render with 3x zoom, so resulting `QImage` would look the same but had size=[240px,150px]

I am new to Qt, so could someone please showed me a working code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform the painter coordinate system:

```
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.scale(3, 3); // zoom 3 times
    painter.translate(-20, -50); // offset origin to 20x50
    // ... render stuff
```

This has an advantage over the other answer, because it will be rendered as if you provided larger coordinates, instead of rendering it small and then enlarging the raster image, which will degrade image quality. Also, it is possible that Qt will optimize it to not render outside of the image, so it will render less, and you don't need to crop and throw results away.

Result:

[image]

Compare that to an upscaled raster:

[image]

Comment: Exactly. Now ... if only there was some cropping mechanism in QPainter, so it wouldn't need to render rest of picture.

Comment: @user2614242 - cropping is a raster operation. What you want is to "crop" the actual vectors. Vector software has tools to intersect, combine and do such things to vectors, but there is no such thing in Qt. You will have to implement it yourself, which is rather complex. You have to trace paths, cut and create new compounds paths.

Comment: Actually Qt has some functionality in this regard, but it is fairly rudimentary relative to vector graphics software.

Comment: Also, your best bet is that Qt is internally smart enough to skip rendering regions outside of the render target's dimensions. It is a very obvious optimization, I would be very surprised if it is not included. You can use `QElapsedTimer` to benchmark and verify if offset rendering is faster than full rendering. Also, you might want to profile in the same resolution to minimize the effect of pixel fill rates, do it without the scaling.

Comment: Adjusting the target's dimensions seems to be working - at least if I set QImage size to [160,150] it produces only 2/3 of x length - effectively cropping it. So the only thing left is to benchmark it, to check if it really renders only region defined by target dimension's.

Comment: @user2614242 "if only there was some cropping mechanism in QPainter, so it wouldn't need to render rest of picture" It doesn't render the rest of the picture. There is a bit of geometry calculations that are done, but the segmentation (the expensive step in rasterization) and blending is skipped for invisible areas. Remember that in Qt, all rendering is done on a target. When the target doesn't exist, rendering literally cannot be done. It's impossible for Qt to "render" outside of the image - the whole pipeline doesn't support it at all.

Answer (score -1):

I've got a code example for you. But it isn't that hard to find out how. You just have to read the documentation, all is easy to find. Qt's documentation is really great.

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);

QImage img(100, 100, QImage::Format_ARGB32);

QPainterPath path;
path.addRect(20, 20, 60, 60);

path.moveTo(0, 0);
path.cubicTo(99, 0,  50, 50,  99, 99);
path.cubicTo(0, 99,  50, 50,  0, 0);

QPainter painter(&img);
painter.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100, Qt::white);
painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(79, 106, 25), 1, Qt::SolidLine,
                    Qt::FlatCap, Qt::MiterJoin));
painter.setBrush(QColor(122, 163, 39));

painter.drawPath(path);
painter.end();

QPixmap pixmap( QPixmap::fromImage(img).copy(20, 50, 80, 50).scaled(240,150) );

// option 1, use a QLabel ( only for simple cases )
QLabel label;
label.setPixmap( pixmap );
label.show();

// option 2, use a QGraphicsScene ( far more flexible )
QGraphicsView view;
QGraphicsScene scene;
scene.addPixmap( pixmap );
scene.setSceneRect( img.rect() );
view.setScene(&scene);
view.show();

return a.exec();
```

Comment: Scaling rasterized vectors up is a very poor idea... It ruins the visual quality. Also, drawing everything, just to have half of it cropped away doesn't sound very efficient.

Comment: Whether my answer is ok depends on your needs. If you want to crop and scale a simple Image, it's enough, otherwise for vector graphics you should of course ddrivers solution